# Jquery to call next step after returning false?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am writing validation on a custom dropdown DD1 and DD2, but when it checks for DD1, and return false, it doesn't check for DD2. Can you please suggest me?

In the below script, i am calling Validatechecked function where it checks whether the dropdown has selected values, it works for only one dropdown. How to make it work for more than 2 dropdowns??

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function Validatechecked(val) {
            var selectedItems = "";

            $('[id*='+val+']'+"  "+ "input:checked").each(function () {
                if (selectedItems == "") {
                    selectedItems = "Selected Items:\r\n\r\n";
                }
                selectedItems += $(this).next().html() + "\r\n";
            });
            if (selectedItems == "") {
                selectedItems = "";
                return false;

            }
            else {
                selectedItems = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {



            $('[id*="InsertNSTBtn"]').click(function () {

                if (!Validatechecked("DD1")) {
                    $('#<%=valid1.ClientID%>').html("*");
                    return false;
                }

                if (!Validatechecked("DD2")) {
                    $('#<%=Valid1.ClientID%>').html("*");
                     return false;
                }
                });

            });
```

Comment: There is no `language` attribute to the `<script>` tag (it's deprecated).  Consider running your code through JSLint.

Comment: Why did this question get down-voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning false right away, set a Boolean variable to false and return that:

```
$('[id*="InsertNSTBtn"]').click(function () {
    var passtest = true;
    if (!Validatechecked("DD1")) {
        $('#<%=RMktallocvalid.ClientID%>').html("*");
        passtest = false;
    }

    if (!Validatechecked("DD2")) {
        $('#<%=SrvRgnMDDValid.ClientID%>').html("*");
        passtest = false;
    }

    /* add more tests if you like */

    return passtest;
});
```

Comment: If i dont return false, my page dont stay at client side...it goes to server side click event and starts running the code